# Spring dependency injection to controller not in constructor

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, controller, autowired

I have a controller which has a constructor like this:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @Autowired
    public SomeController(final AutowiredBean1 autowiredBean1,
                                 final AutowiredBean2 autowiredBean2,
                                 final AutowiredBean3 autowiredBean3,
                                 final AutowiredBean4 autowiredBean4,
                                 final AutowiredBean5 autowiredBean5,
                                 final AutowiredBean6 autowiredBean6,
                                 final AutowiredBean7 autowiredBean7) {
        this.autowiredBean1 = autowiredBean1;
        this.autowiredBean2 = autowiredBean2;
        this.autowiredBean3 = autowiredBean3;
        this.autowiredBean4 = autowiredBean4;
        this.autowiredBean5 = autowiredBean5;
        this.autowiredBean6 = autowiredBean6;
        this.autowiredBean7 = autowiredBean7;
    }
}
```

And I have a sonarQ quality gate that does not allow me to put more than 7 parameter in a cosnstructor, How would you inject any number of parameters in the constructor, without using xml-based application context and without loosing the singleton properties?

I know there might be some clever ways to do this, but I don't know where exactly where to look at, so if you could point me some example that would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: Break your fat controller to smaller ones

Comment: This controller is small enough, it just needs 8 already defined beans to function correctly. any ideas?

Comment: why do you need to have a constructor?

Comment: Spring Team recommends: "Always use constructor based dependency injection in your beans. Always use assertions for mandatory dependencies"

Comment: You also can remove the @autowired annotation since spring 4.3